# Ошибки npm пакета socks-proxy-agent: как правильно реализовать проксирование запросов через Socks5 TOR?

Tags: node.js, axios, tor, socks5

**node.js** - **v14.15.4**
**Vue** - **@vue/cli 4.5.11**
Разработка и отладка - **WebStorm 2020.2**

При запуске сервера разработки *(vue-cli-service serve)* **socks-proxy-agent** тянет устаревшую **dns**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке установить эту зависимость - куча предупреждений с ошибкой несоответствия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Socks Proxy** агент используется для перенаправления запросов через сеть **Tor**.

```
import { SocksProxyAgent } from 'socks-proxy-agent'
import Axios from 'axios'
import Vue from 'vue'

const config = require('../app/config/main.config.js')
const agent = new SocksProxyAgent('socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050')
const CreateAxios = AxiosCreate(  '//' + config.SERVER_IP + ':' + config.SERVER_PORT + '/api')

function AxiosCreate(baseURL) {

    return Axios.create({

        withCredentials: true,
        baseURL,
        headers: {

            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        },
        timeout: 5000,
        httpAgent: agent
    })
}

export default {
    install() {
        Vue.prototype.$http = CreateAxios
    }
}
```

Попытки поиска подобной ошибки с dns-зависимостью не увенчались успехом.
Предложите рабочий способ с вменяемым Socks Proxy агентом для проксирования запросов через Tor.
Благодарю.

Comment: не знаю, что деалет `socks-proxy-agent`, но есть ощущение, что тоже самое, что и это -  https://cli.vuejs.org/ru/config/#devserver-proxy

Comment: Совсем другое предназначение.. Дословно - модуль "socks-proxy-agent" предоставляет реализацию http.Agent, который подключается к указанному прокси-серверу SOCKS и может использоваться со встроенными модулями http и https. Я не могу подобрать рабочий npm пакет для проксирования через Socks5 в Tor сеть.

Comment: Никто совсем не знает что ли?

Comment: почему-то, мне кажется, что этот пакет только для сервера, а вы его на фронт тянете

Comment: так ведь работа axios предполагается с фронта, а socks-proxy-agent всего лишь sock-агент для axios - https://www.npmjs.com/package/socks-proxy-agent. думаю тут в другом дело.